# Disable pr merge button when auto build in progress or fail

Tags: merge, bitbucket, restriction

Enable merge button in the pull request only after auto build success that too specific branch patterns. (branch level) ex: feature/XX_XX -->master PR only need to check  the build status. If auto build is in progress, PR merge button should not enable.

Pls let
me know if any option for this.
We have 500+ developers, will not wait for auto build to complete and merge the PR which leads wrong code to master branch which is golden source code

It’s a data centre /server

Pls help me. Fyi
I don’t want minimum successful builds option because it’s a repo level.
I want at branch level… in multi branch pipeline we will only enable specific patterns., because developers volume is high. And we don’t have that much resources of build servers

Answer (score 0):

This is configurable in the **Repo settings -> Branch restrictions -> Add a branch restrictions**. You can use either a **branch name** (just type the branch name) or branch patterns and check no failed builds and no builds in progress.

[image: Bitbucket repo settings Pull Request]

Comment: Actually in our bitbucket we cannot see bitbucket merge settings option.

Comment: Strange, this comparison chart https://www.atlassian.com/migration/assess/compare-cloud-data-center/bitbucket (scroll down a bit) says that "Enforced merge checks" it is available for both cloud and data center. Not sure what the licensing model for data center is, maybe it requires some premium license (?), or is available starting on some version. I'd say, try to reach out to Atlassian and ask them.

Comment: I think @Gec posted a screenshot for Bitbucket Cloud branch restrictions. My understanding is that BB DC/Server offers the "required successful builds' feature on *repo* / *project* level (included in license) while BB Cloud offers the feature on *branch* level. You need a *premium* license for BB Cloud to actually enforce the required builds count for pull request (or use Workzone for BB Cloud).

Comment: Yes, the screenshot is from BB Cloud (I do not have access to a BB Data Center installation). "Enforced merge checks" (which Atlassian says is supported on Data Center too) sounds to me like it's exactly what the OP was looking for. I might be mistaken though, the Data Center edition might have different repo / branch / merge options.